# Is there an application like Connectify for OS X El Capitan?

Tags: wifi, software-recommendation, macos

There is a well known app for Windows named Connectify, used to share a Wi-Fi connection between a computer that only has Wi-Fi with other devices which requests that connection from the computer.

This would be useful for example to connect a Chromecast to a hotel's Wi-Fi that has one of those captive password situations through your laptop which has an interface to let you enter the password.

What's the best alternative for this app on OS X El Capitan?

*Please provide the whole procedure.*

This is not possible with OS X built-in Internet Sharing.

Comment: It's called Internet Sharing and it's actually built in (no application required). See http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/05/enable-internet-sharing-mac-os-x/, https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13855

Comment: @patrix This is incorrect. When you are connected to wifi you cannot open a wifi hotspot. This is something that connectify allows but it's only available for windows.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible without additional (external, peripheral) hardware.

> Your Mac’s physical Wi-Fi interface can either be connected to a Wi-Fi network or host its own network. It can only do one of these things at a time. This means you can’t be both connected to a Wi-Fi network and sharing that Wi-Fi network’s connection over Wi-Fi. Yes, you may sometimes want to do this — for example, when you’re staying in a hotel or other location that only allows you to connect one device to its Wi-Fi network.

from http://www.howtogeek.com/214053/how-to-turn-your-mac-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/